# Prevent html content below div (height determined by jquery to fill viewport) from loading before div has loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had some help getting a div to fill the viewport height using jquery with my bootstrap html structure.

[Here is a fiddle of my page and structure](https://jsfiddle.net/Katrina_B/5n5uv8q1/).

you can't really tell in the fiddle what the problem is, but when i load my real page in the web browser, the #remainder div shows directly under the header for a few seconds while jquery is determining the viewport height, and then finally the page loads properly and the #remainder content goes below the fold where it should be.

Obviously it all happens in a second or less, but its ugly and annoying and distracting to see. How can i prevent html below the #jumbo div from loading until jumbo height has been determined? Or is there some other way I should be thinking about the problem?

**Here is the jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function adjustJumboHeight() {
    var headerHeight = $("#headerContainer").outerHeight();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    var remains = viewportHeight - headerHeight;
    $("#jumbo").css({
      "height": remains
    });
  }
  // On page load
  adjustJumboHeight();
  // on resize (or mobile orientation change)
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    adjustJumboHeight();
  });
});
```

**and here is my bootstrap 4 html:**

```
<div id="headerContainer" class="container-fluid">
  <header class="row row-eq-height">
    <div id="logo" class="col-md-3">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8b/58/61/8b5861d8fa21ae898d776631a587acb8.jpg">
    </div>
    <!--logo-->
  </header>
  <!--header-->
</div>
<!--headerContainer-->
<div id="jumbo" class="row"></div>
<div id="remainder">
  <h1>I don't want this content to show till the #jumbo div has fully loaded</h1>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin imperdiet, tortor ac tincidunt mattis, risus justo rutrum nulla, ac porttitor massa augue at est. Aenean pretium ligula at nunc viverra, at lacinia risus lobortis. Curabitur neque leo, tempus
    quis sollicitudin vitae, viverra in libero. Curabitur hendrerit dignissim maximus. Aliquam eu leo vel libero accumsan posuere. Ut rutrum porta leo eu efficitur. Morbi at orci in neque sodales consectetur sit amet et urna. Cras ex ante, varius nec
    tellus in, dictum sagittis mi.</p>
  <p>Proin fermentum tortor sed rhoncus gravida. Etiam sagittis lectus et nisi facilisis, sed cursus lectus tincidunt. Etiam ac risus ut neque interdum accumsan. Maecenas id convallis nibh. Curabitur dapibus eleifend justo, vel porta arcu tempus nec. Quisque mattis sollicitudin quam, id congue nisi pulvinar a. Phasellus eu scelerisque elit. Duis at condimentum erat. Donec in hendrerit tortor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: your text shows in place of the image briefly because the image was still loading while it's container's size is 0 until it's loaded to take its calculated size. meaning you need to fix the size in the CSS of the image container to keep its size even while the image is still loading.

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that your question still hasn't a marked solution. Is this because you simply forgot or is your question still unanswered? I'd be happy to help you further with your case, otherwhise please mark this question as solved as it helps other users for a better experience on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

What you're experiencing is called FOUC (Flash of unstyled content). It occurs when your css is loaded before the javascript.

(read more here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_Unstyled_Content)

There are a few workarounds to this such as using a preloader icon or using this code on github: https://gist.github.com/johnpolacek/3827270

```
<!-- Prevent FOUC (flash of unstyled content) - http://johnpolacek.com/2012/10/03/help-prevent-fouc/ -->
<style type="text/css">
    .no-fouc {display: none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.documentElement.className = 'no-fouc';
    // add to document ready: $('.no-fouc').removeClass('no-fouc');
</script>
```

Another way to fix your problem would be to just set your css class / id (the one that is flashing) `display:none` in your .css file and then `display:inline` in your JQuery load event.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the content for `<div id="remainder">` through an ajax request after the upper part of the page has been rendered.

Keep the  empty.

```
<div id="remainder"></div>
```

And, make the following change to your javascript function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function adjustJumboHeight(){
       ... your code

       // add following three lines
       $.get('<URL>', function(data) {
          $('#remainder').html(data);
       });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `opacity:0` in the css of `#jumbo` like

```
#jumbo{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

and then set `opacity:1` in javascript inside function like

```
function adjustJumboHeight() {
  var headerHeight = $("#headerContainer").outerHeight();
  var viewportHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
  var remains = viewportHeight - headerHeight;
  $("#jumbo").css({
    "height": remains,
    "opacity": 1
  });
}
```